# PhpStorm: the area of one set of Project Files has the background of yellow. The other Project has no such background

Tags: phpstorm

In my PhpStorm, when I open Project A, its background of Project files has a strange color as in the image, meanwhile other projects do not have that such color.

Can anybody help me with that?

Problematic project:

[image: the area of Project A has the background of yellow]

Another project:

[image: The other Project has the normal background]

Comment: Such "yellow" background means that the folder is considered out of the project, e.g. marked as excluded, as a library etc. Perhaps even opened via wrong path (e.g. symlinked)

Comment: You can mess with the settings and try to see what you have done to have it this way . Or do  the following: **1)** Close ALL projects in PhpStorm so that you see the Welcome screen with the list of recent projects **2)** Locate that project there and remove it (right click or click on "x" on hover **3)** Close the IDE completely **4)** Go to that Project root folder and delete `.idea` subfolder (that project settings) **5)** Launch PhpStorm, use "Open" and point to the project root older -- IDE will create a new project from existing files.

Comment: @LazyOne: thank you so much. Your solution works !!!!

Comment: That worked for me as well. I also created an empty .idea file inside of the project folder in order to prevent PHPStorm from creating that folder again